# CSRF issue with Laravel and CKEditor

Tags: php, laravel, ckeditor, csrf

I am integrating CKEditor with Laravel and creating my own image upload handler. So far, so good. However, when I submit my image for upload a TokenMismatchException.

This seems to be getting raised because I am submitting from a form created by a third party which doesn't include a CSRF token.

I was under the impression that you had to explicitly enabled the CSRF filter for them to be checked. I haven't done this so I would have thought that CSRF tokens wouldn't be used and yet they are.

How can I get around this? Is there a way to make a certain route *not* use the CSRF filter?

Comment: `I was under the impression that you had to explicitly enabled the CSRF filter for them to be checked.` that is right. are you sure you are NOT filtering them? Laravel filters can be handle globally. it may not appear easily while reviewing.

Comment: Aha, you're right. Put it in an answer and I'll accept it if you like. Someone had added it in the BaseController.